# Interacting with WMI via .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, wmi-service

I need to get information about system such as: motherboard info, hdd info,  e.t.c. in OS Windows. I can get it from wmi service. But I need to gather it with .NET core application.

I know in .NET application there interface IWbemServices to interact with WMI service, but I can't find something similar in .NET core.

So I have a questions:

- Can I create COM object with .NET core application. If it's "yes" then how can I do it?
- Are there other ways to get information about hardware, through .NET core?

Comment: Why do you want to interact with COM and WMI from a .NET Core application? .NET Core is cross-platform, but COM/WMI are Windows-specific. Maybe it would make sense to build a .NET Framework project instead?

Comment: as I said, I need some hardware information, such as Motherboard, cpu or RAM information. And it should be .net core app.

Comment: A .NET Core app that only runs on Windows?

Comment: for Linux there is other solution.

Comment: @Nate Barbettini net core compiled for net461 is very common eg use Asp.Net Core ( and its modern libs) but have a win32 dependency - Service fabric , Event Store etc etc

Comment: @NateBarbettini .Net Core has quite a few performance enhancements over the more robust .Net Framework. An ASP.Net Core application can run with much better performance. Not to mention some of the language goodies.

Comment: did you try Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/ ?

Comment: WMI  in Linux ? COM/WMI are Windows-specific.It is only for Windows, NetCore 3.1 with WMI (Management) doesnt' work in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query is now available in [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) under `System.Management`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not actually work with SCD in Dot Net Core. System.Management is dependent on COM interop which there is no near future solution to. https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/6728

Comment: What's about https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/. ?

Comment: I'm getting an "EventLog access is not supported on this platform"  error when I add the Windows Compatibility pack to my .Net Core app.